# Any way to completely change how a code piece looks in editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've done extensive search in VSCode's docs, and it seems that the answer is no, but I still hope it's possible.

I want to completely change how some code piece in editor looks, as if I had full access to it's HTML and CSS. For example, I want to change font, opacity, size, and even add custom `<image>`s or other elements. Is it possible? If no, what is the closest solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. The closest you can get is using the [text decorator](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/decorator-sample) api.

The other option is to build a completely custom editor/preview using the [webview api](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/webview).

Comment: A needed this confirmation. Thanks